# How to ask which (sub)site to ask a question in when you've just made an account?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I've got a question that seemed to fall between two of the stack-exchange sites ('Programmers' and 'Workplace'). Reading the rules carefully, I could cross one of them off my list (it's very clear the question is inappropriate for 'Programmers' from the rules there).

So, reading the rules of *this* site says to ask in the meta of the specific subsite if the rules seem unclear. Except that requires 5 reputation.

This is probably not much, but it seems a bit 'gamey'/cynical to either think of a great question/answer just so I can get my meta-question answered.

My apologies if this seems out of place, but my original question now seems to have generated a meta- and a meta-meta- question. I don't know where else to ask [ except maybe Douglas Hofstadter ;-) ]

In any case, my the meta-question would have been, in the Workplace-meta, wether the original question, which was *'Can I apply for a job as Embedded C++ Programmer with just normal C++ experience and an MSc. in CompSci?'* can be asked in Workplace without bending the rules too much (which could maybe sort-of allow it if you read the rules somewhat leniently).

Comment: You did the metaright thing. Site recommendations come here, esp. from 1-rep users. The tag is an indication.

Comment: That's good to know at least.